# Firebase Database console.log() returning Null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, console.log

I hope to seek help from someone if possible. In the following code. Im trying to `console.log()` data from My Firebase reference as you can see in my code below. But the `Console.log()` is returning null instead of the values that are there in Firebase Realtime Database. I have also provided the code for adding which is working well. Please have a look the image of my database if it helps. I am not getting any other error in my console except the fact that this is returning `null`.
[image]

```
function addFamilyMember() {
  var NameOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberName").value;
  var DoBOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberDoB").value;
  var EmailOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberEmail").value;
  var ContactOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberContactNo").value;

 if (
  NameOfMember.length == "" ||
  DoBOfMember.length == "" ||
  EmailOfMember.length == "" ||
  ContactOfMember.length == ""
) {
   alert("Please enter all details of your Family Member");
} else {
   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   var uid;
   if (user != null) {
     uid = user.uid;
   }

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/Family/" + NameOfMember)
  .set({
    MemberName: NameOfMember,
    MemberDOB: DoBOfMember,
    MemberEmail: EmailOfMember,
    MemberContact: ContactOfMember,
  });
 }
}

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid;
if (user != null) {
uid = user.uid;
}

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/Family/")
  .on("value", function (snap) {
    var mName = snap.child("MemberName").val();
    var mDOB = snap.child("MemberDOB").val();
    var mEmail = snap.child("MemberEmail").val();
    var mContact = snap.child("MemberContact").val();

    console.log(mName + " " + mEmail + " " + mContact + " " + mDOB);
});
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot from your Firebase Console? All path names are case sensitive. Also can you edit the question and paste the value which is logged on `console.log(snap.val())`

Comment: @Dharmaraj The screenshot is shared of the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading the page for the first time, `firebase.auth().currentUser` shouldn't be used because Firebase Auth needs to [check if the user's login session is valid first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

```
let currentUserFamilyRef = null;

// for use with .on("value") and .off("value")
function onValueFamilyListener(snapshot) {
  const familyMembers = [];
  snapshot.forEach((familyMemberSnapshot) => {
    const MemberName = snap.child("MemberName").val();
    const MemberDOB = snap.child("MemberDOB").val();
    const MemberEmail = snap.child("MemberEmail").val();
    const MemberContact = snap.child("MemberContact").val();
    
    familyMembers.push({ MemberName, MemberDOB, MemberEmail, MemberContact });

    console.log(MemberName + " " + MemberDOB + " " + MemberEmail + " " + MemberContact);
  }

  // TODO: do something with the array of family members familyMembers
}

// for showing loading state
function showLoadingIcon(visible) {
  if (visible) {
    // TODO: show the icon
    // TODO: disable the submit button
  } else {
    // TODO: hide the icon
    // TODO: enable the submit button
  }
}

// for when addFamilyMember() is called while signed out
function addFamilyMemberSignedOut() {
  alert('You need to sign in first!');
  return false;
}

// for when addFamilyMember() is called while signed in
function addFamilyMemberSignedIn() {
  const NameOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberName").value;
  const DoBOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberDoB").value;
  const EmailOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberEmail").value;
  const ContactOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberContactNo").value;

  if (
    NameOfMember.length == "" ||
    DoBOfMember.length == "" ||
    EmailOfMember.length == "" ||
    ContactOfMember.length == ""
  ) {
    alert("Please enter all details of your Family Member");
    return false;
  }
  
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  
  if (user === null) {
    // shouldn't get here, but just in case.
    alert('You need to sign in first!');
    return false;
  }
  
  const uid = user.uid;
  
  showLoadingIcon(true);

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/Family/" + encodeURIComponent(NameOfMember)) // escape names as they may contain symbols, etc.
    .set({
      MemberName: NameOfMember,
      MemberDOB: DoBOfMember,
      MemberEmail: EmailOfMember,
      MemberContact: ContactOfMember,
    })
    .then(
      () => {
        // saved family member's data successfully
        showLoadingIcon(false);
        // reset form
        document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberName").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberDoB").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberEmail").value = "";
        document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberContactNo").value = "";
        alert('Information saved!');
      },
      (err) => {
        // failed to save family member's data
        showLoadingIcon(false);
        // err.code may lead to more specific error information
        console.error(err);
        alert('Failed to save information!');
      }
    );
}

// for calling the correct addFamilyMember version
let addFamilyMember = addFamilyMemberSignedOut;

showLoadingIcon(true); // while loading the user's info, show a loading icon

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // A user is (newly/already) signed in.
    // create a reference for this user's family
    const newUserFamilyRef = firebase.database()
      .ref("/Users/" + user.uid + "/Family");
    if (currentUserFamilyRef !== null) {
      // if the old user and new user are the same, do nothing
      // but if they've changed, remove the old listener and update currentUserFamilyRef
      if (!currentUserFamilyRef.isEqual(newUserFamilyRef)) {
        currentUserFamilyRef.off("value", onValueFamilyListener);
        currentUserFamilyRef = newUserFamilyRef;
      }
    } else {
      currentUserFamilyRef = newUserFamilyRef;
    }
    // use the "signed in" version of addFamilyMember
    addFamilyMember = addFamilyMemberSignedIn;
    // attach listener to "/users/{user.uid}/Family"
    currentUserFamilyRef.on("value", onValueFamilyListener);
  } else {
    // no user is signed in.
    // use the "not signed in" version of addFamilyMember
    addFamilyMember = addFamilyMemberSignedOut;
    // if a user was logged in, clean up it's listener to prevent errors
    if (currentUserFamilyRef !== null) {
      currentUserFamilyRef.off("value", onValueFamilyListener);
    }
    // no user, so set the reference to null
    currentUserFamilyRef = null;
  }
  showLoadingIcon(false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will surely go through the code and use it to the best.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are fetching the whole Family node and trying to access data of each member.
I tried to recreate your database structure and got this in console on running the code.

```
{
  "Name One": {"MemberContact":10000,"MemberName":"Name Two"},
  "Name Two": {"MemberContact":10002,"MemberName":"Name Two"}
}
```

so if you want to get data of each user from that then try using `forEach` this way.

```
Object.keys(snap.val()).forEach(key => {
  const memberData = snap.val()[key]
  //Data of each member
  var mName = memberData["MemberName"]
  var mDOB = memberData["MemberDOB"]
  var mEmail = memberData["MemberEmail"]
  var mContact = memberData["MemberContact"]
  console.log(mName + " " + mEmail + " " + mContact + " " + mDOB);
})
```

Comment: Instead of `Object.keys(snap.val()).forEach(key => {`, I recommend using Firebase's built-in `snap.forEach()` operation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use firebase.auth().currentUser. First you need to check the authentication state of the user. Then only you can ask for the current user. So to do this you need to wrap it using authentication state observer.You can read more about it on firebase documentation: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start][1]

```js
function addFamilyMember() {
    var NameOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberName").value;
    var DoBOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberDoB").value;
    var EmailOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberEmail").value;
    var ContactOfMember = document.getElementById("newFamilyMemberContactNo").value;
  
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
   if (
    NameOfMember.length == "" ||
    DoBOfMember.length == "" ||
    EmailOfMember.length == "" ||
    ContactOfMember.length == ""
  ) {
     alert("Please enter all details of your Family Member");
  } else {
     var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     var uid;
     if (user != null) {
       uid = user.uid;
     }
  
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/Family/" + NameOfMember)
    .set({
      MemberName: NameOfMember,
      MemberDOB: DoBOfMember,
      MemberEmail: EmailOfMember,
      MemberContact: ContactOfMember,
    });
   }
  }
  
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid;
  if (user != null) {
  uid = user.uid;
  }
  
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/Family/")
    .on("value", function (snap) {
      var mName = snap.child("MemberName").val();
      var mDOB = snap.child("MemberDOB").val();
      var mEmail = snap.child("MemberEmail").val();
      var mContact = snap.child("MemberContact").val();
  
      console.log(mName + " " + mEmail + " " + mContact + " " + mDOB);
  })
})}
```